# Adding with multiple variables, same line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to use `+=1` in the same line for multiple variables?

E.g.

```
i = 1
x = 3
i, x += 1
```

This throws a `SyntaxError`.

However, I can do:

```
i, x = i + 1, x + 1
```

Is that the "only" way to simply add one to a variable?

Comment: No you can not. I do not see the purpose in you doing this.

Comment: @XhulianoBrace - Just to save a line or two when adding to variables.  I will think more as you say, there's likely a better way to do this and/or avoid having to altogether...(Also of course "no you can not" is a good Answer).

Comment: Python does not support that kind of design. Without implementing a convoluted container class for the variables you want to simultaneously modify, there is no way to do it in a single statement. The overhead required for that would be much more than the handful of lines you would save. You could of course use a semicolon to write two statements on the same line, but the practice is frowned upon as it really has no benefit and harms readability. `i += 1; x += 1`.

Comment: @SyntaxVoidsupportsMonica - Thanks for that, I was figuring that would be the case (and creating some ridiculous container class for this is wayyyy overkill as you get at).